# neural network: what kind of continuity do we get?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I think standard neural nets are continuous functions, since they are compositions of functions, alternating between linear transformations by the weights and some differentiable nonlinearity. But what kind of continuity do we get? If we have an L-layered deep network, is the overall function continuous enough so that its sensitivity to initial conditions (during forward propagation) is not too bad? Is there a theorem about this?

I would appreciate if you can point me to some papers... For example, this seems to be related: [Back Propagation is Sensitive to Initial Conditions](http://www.demo.cs.brandeis.edu/papers/bpsic.pdf), but I hope to see the results about forward propagation.

Comment: This feels off-topic here. Furthermore: what is your definition of sensitivity? Most NNs currently used are even not-differentiable (Relu -> subgradients) and sensitivy is probably more about convex vs. non-convex (nearly all real-world NNs are non-convex). As even general non-convex Quadratic-programming is NP-hard, you can get an idea about how bad this is theory-wise.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure where to ask this question...

Right, I guess my notion of sensitivity here is similar to continuity. I want to know if the input changes a little, how much does this tiny change affects the change of the output, so I guess it is basically a question about gradient... Thanks a lot!